# build ruby 1.8.7 on alpine

Tags: ruby, docker, alpine-linux

i get this error when i try to compile ruby 1.8.7

```
BUILD FAILED (Alpine Linux 3.8.2 using ruby-build 20181225)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20190128170412.7047
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20190128170412.7047.log

Last 10 log lines:
     return ossl_x509crl_sk2ary(pkcs7_get_certs_or_crls(self, 0));
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ossl_pkcs7.c:11:0:
ossl.h:118:7: note: expected 'struct stack_st_X509_CRL *' but argument is of type 'int *'
 VALUE ossl_x509crl_sk2ary(STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *crl);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [Makefile:188: ossl_pkcs7.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20190128170412.7047/ruby-1.8.7/ext/openssl'
make: *** [Makefile:285: all] Error 1
```

this is my Docker file I am using

```
FROM alpine

ENV RUBY_VERSION "1.8.7"

ENV RUBYBUILD_PACKAGES \
  build-base \
  autoconf \
  git \
  subversion \
  bison \
  zlib-dev \
  openssl-dev \
  yaml-dev \
  readline-dev \
  ncurses-dev \
  libffi-dev \
  gdbm-dev

ENV RUBYLIB_PACKAGES \
  zlib \
  openssl \
  yaml \
  readline \
  ncurses \
  libffi \
  gdbm

ENV EXTRA_PACKAGES \
  ca-certificates \
  bash \
  curl

RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add $RUBYBUILD_PACKAGES $RUBYLIB_PACKAGES $EXTRA_PACKAGES && \
    git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git /tmp/ruby-build
RUN cd /tmp/ruby-build && ./install.sh && cd - && rm -rf /tmp/ruby-build
```

here is the full log

https://gist.github.com/nkhine/0b7f5c162313946ddd2f8d7feb57144a

any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Maybe try another SSL lib? I had similar issue (like interface in headers had changed) while building wkhtmltopdf and it was because it expected an older version of openssl or something. So I ended up using libssl1.0@3.8 and libcrypto1.0@3.8. (3.8 here is a reference to 3.8 repo of alpine)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to build ruby 1.8.7 on alpine with older version openssl (e.g. 1.0.1e). So the problen was as @ivan-yurov said.